# Permissions for .git/ for each working directory

Tags: git, git-push, git-pull

I get this error every time I git push. Only for this working directory. Not in another similar one, where from what I can tell has the same permissions.

```
$ git push
Counting objects: 15, done.
Compressing objects: 100% (7/7), done.
Writing objects: 100% (8/8), 683 bytes, done.
Total 8 (delta 5), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote: Sending mail...
To git@devel.site.com:mysite.git
dd36358..86bc572  redesign -> redesign
! [rejected]        master -> master (non-fast-forward)
error: failed to push some refs to 'git@devel.site.com:mysite.git'
To prevent you from losing history, non-fast-forward updates were rejected
Merge the remote changes (e.g. 'git pull') before pushing again.  See the
'Note about fast-forwards' section of 'git push --help' for details.
```

Is this a permissions issue? git pull seems to work fine and git push seems to go through too but I still get the error.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

**Ahem**

> ```
> Merge the remote changes (e.g. 'git pull') before pushing again.
> ```

This really doesn't *look* like a permissions problem to me.

Comment: I can successfully run git pull. I still get the error when running git push, as well as git push going through successfully.

Answer (score 0):

It's not a permissions issue; see the error message:

> error: failed to push some refs to 'git@devel.site.com:mysite.git'
>   To prevent you from losing history, non-fast-forward updates were rejected
>   Merge the remote changes (e.g. 'git pull') before pushing again.  See the
>   'Note about fast-forwards' section of 'git push --help' for details.

The "note about fast-forwards" section of `git push --help` has a lengthy explanation of the problem, but in short; the branch you're pushing to isn't a direct ancestor of your current branch, so the remote server won't let you push. You need to fix your local changes (e.g. `git pull` to get changes you're missing, or `git rebase` to rebase your changes onto the remote head), or force the remote server to accept the push with `--force` (the latter is almost never the right move)

Comment: I can successfully run git pull. I still get the error when running git push, as well as git push going through successfully. I'll look into git rebase now.

Comment: I'm getting lost reading the documentation. I run git rebase redesign. I get Current branch is up to date.

Comment: @win Don't just rebase randomly, it was just a suggestion. You need to find out why your current branch isn't connected to the remote head and fix it; you can try reading `git log`, or `git gui` to get a graphical view of your repository

Answer (score 0):

In case this is still a problem, if you do `git push`, you're pushing all your branches, not just the current one.

`git pull` is NOT a direct opposite to `git push`, however. It is exactly the same as doing the following commands:

```
git fetch
git merge origin/thecurrentbranch
```

That is, `git pull` only merges the working branch. It does NOT merge any other branches.

If `git pull` comes up clean, but you still can't push, it means that one of your other branches is out of date, and that's what git is complaining about.

The solution is to only push your current branch:

```
git push origin thecurrentbranch
```

Note that I assume `thecurrentbranch` is the name of your active branch, and `origin` is your up-stream repository.

EDIT: Taking a close look at your original question is enlightening:

```
dd36358..86bc572  redesign -> redesign
! [rejected]        master -> master (non-fast-forward)
```

You probably have `redesign` checked out, and so this is what `git pull` is operating on. However, git is rejecting the `master` branch. So, to resolve this specific problem, either push `redesign` explicitly, or do this:

```
git checkout master
git merge origin/master
git push
```